# Set ViewPager Inside ScrollView without specifying it's height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to set view pager inside ScrollView but it's not showing without specifying specific height.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/svRecord"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/pager"
                     />
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Is there any why to set scrollview without specifying height?

I tried to set it's height 0dp and assign weight 1 but it's still not showing.

Answer (score 2):

ViewPager doesn’t support wrap_content as it stands now because it doesn’t load all of its children at the same time, meaning it can’t get an appropriate measurement. So customize it like this one :)

```
public class MagicViewPager extends ViewPager {

public MagicViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // super has to be called in the beginning so the child views can be
    // initialized.
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    if (getChildCount() <= 0)
        return;

    // Check if the selected layout_height mode is set to wrap_content
    // (represented by the AT_MOST constraint).
    boolean wrapHeight = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec)
            == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST;

    int width = getMeasuredWidth();

    View firstChild = getChildAt(0);

    // Initially set the height to that of the first child - the
    // PagerTitleStrip (since we always know that it won't be 0).
    int height = firstChild.getMeasuredHeight();

    if (wrapHeight) {

        // Keep the current measured width.
        widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

    }

    int fragmentHeight = 0;
    fragmentHeight = measureFragment(((Fragment) getAdapter().instantiateItem(this, getCurrentItem())).getView());

    // Just add the height of the fragment:
    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height + fragmentHeight,
            MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

    // super has to be called again so the new specs are treated as
    // exact measurements.
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

public int measureFragment(View view) {
    if (view == null)
        return 0;

    view.measure(0, 0);
    return view.getMeasuredHeight();
}}
```

Comment: btw, I wrote WCViewPager class that handles wrap_content nicely (also in cases where children are not the same size):
https://github.com/rnevet/WCViewPager

Comment: definitely doesn't work for regular PagerAdapter but it's close

Answer (score 1):

Every view declared in xml files must have the layout_height and layout_width present. If you are setting the height for the ViewPager through your java code then you can just set height to 0dp and before rendering the view make sure to set its layout parameters in the java code.

Comment: I tried to set it programmatically, but still not working :(


LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
 tabView.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: No you should not use match_parent, but actually calculate the view size and pass them into layoutparams

Comment: But view size is dynamic in every View.Which is setting in viewpager

Comment: yes after loading the views in the viewpager add up all the sizes of the views and set it as the height for the viewpager. Btw have you tried using wrap_content?

Comment: This solution works for me thanks @Bhargav http://www.henning.ms/2013/09/09/viewpager-that-simply-dont-measure-up/

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that ScrollView needs to know the exact height of all its child views before it can be rendered. The hight of the viewpager is not known until its pages are loaded.